# Location Doesn't Stop Showing And Keep On Updating

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps

I Made An App That Gets The User's Location And Shows Information About The Location.
**But The Problem Is That It Doesn't Stop Showing Location And It's Keep On Updating On The Same Location.**
I Made A Toast And Once The App Runs Then The Toast Also Doesn't Go Off The Screen.
It's Like The Location Is Running An Infinite Loop Or Something But I Just Can't Figure It Out.

```
    package com.example.mymap;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.location.Address;
    import android.location.Geocoder;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
   
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Locale;

    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
                mMap.clear();
                LatLng Helsinki = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Helsinki).title("Here!").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Helsinki));
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                try {
                    List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                    if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                        String address = "";
                        if (addressList.get(0).getThoroughfare() != null) {
                            address += addressList.get(0).getThoroughfare() + " ";
                        }

                        if (addressList.get(0).getLocality() != null) {
                            address += addressList.get(0).getLocality() + " ";
                        }

                        if (addressList.get(0).getPostalCode() != null) {
                            address += addressList.get(0).getPostalCode() + " ";
                        }

                        if (addressList.get(0).getAdminArea() != null) {
                            address += addressList.get(0).getAdminArea();
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i("Address", address);

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 23) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        } else {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            } else {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                Location lastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                mMap.clear();
                LatLng Helsinki = new LatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Helsinki).title("Here!").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Helsinki));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Debugging Details But The Debugger Was Manually Stopped As It Was Updating The Same Location Infinitely.**

```
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=27KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=28KB
I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=61KB, data=44KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=61KB, data=44KB
Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa3fb3f80, tid 8221
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, 
retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa6b870a0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
I/Address: Avenue de Suffren Paris 75007 Île-de-France
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa6b870a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa6b83900)
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa405d6c0, tid 8218
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa6b870a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa6b83900)
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x91663780: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x91663780: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0x9111b310)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa6b870a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa6b83900)
I/Address: Avenue de Suffren Paris 75007 Île-de-France
I/Address: Avenue de Suffren Paris 75007 Île-de-France
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa6b870a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa6b83900)
I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=123KB, data=120KB
After code cache collection, code=102KB, data=81KB
I/Address: Avenue de Suffren Paris 75007 Île-de-France
I/Address: Avenue de Suffren Paris 75007 Île-de-France
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:6
Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 6
W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa6b870a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa6b83900)
I/Address: Avenue de Suffren Paris 75007 Île-de-France
I/Address: Avenue de Suffren Paris 75007 Île-de-France
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa6b870a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa6b83900)
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=122KB, data=97KB
I/Address: Avenue de Suffren Paris 75007 Île-de-France
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=122KB, data=97KB
Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
I/Address: Avenue de Suffren Paris 75007 Île-de-France
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 23) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5, 100, locationListener);
    } else {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        } else {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5, 100, locationListener);
            Location lastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            mMap.clear();
            LatLng Helsinki = new LatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Helsinki).title("Here!").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Helsinki));
        }
    }
}
```

**The Above Code Has Changement In The Values.**
Just Have To Change The Time Of Updating From 0 Minutes And 0 Meters To Some Value Like 5 Minute And 100 Meters. And It Will Solve Everything.

**Single Line Example From The Code Itself:**

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5, 200, locationListener);
```